# Highcharts xAxis update every day

Tags: datetime, highcharts

I want to make a highchart in angular and asp.net that is updated when a new item is added in the database. I made an HTML form and an addPoint method that activates when the add button is pressed. My question is how to sum how many time the button is press on a specific day (ex: if the button is press on 20 Aug
10 times to add the 10 value in chart series and if the button is press on a new day to add a new date in xAxis).

This is how my code looks like https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-forked-eulg0?file=/src/app/app.component.ts

Thank you.

Comment: Hi @Ashley, Could you describe the problem more precisely? Do you want to store the number of clicks in a database and use it to get a chart data?

Comment: yes,i want   to count how many times the button is clicked in one day to add that value in the chart series

Comment: if that is not possible i want to add in the x Axis the real date time value when the button was pressed

Comment: It is possible, you can get data for a chart from a database and update your database on every click.

Comment: How can i do this?

Comment: Hi @Ashley, Here you can find a very basic example with online JSON hosting: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/kv3n8gbm/